# Showing equivalence of definitions for Zermelo Hierarchy

Tags: logic, set-theory

I want to prove the equivalence of the following recursive definitions for a set hierarchy:

First,

Set $V_0 =\emptyset$. Then given $V_\alpha$, set $V_{\alpha+1}=\mathcal{P}(V_\alpha)$. And if $\lambda$ is a limit ordinal, then set $V_\lambda =\bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda} V_\alpha$.

Second,

Set $V_\alpha =\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal{P}(V_\beta)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathsf{ON}$.

(Of course, the case for $V_0$ is clear.)

So we use induction. I understand how to use it and what we want to show, but I can't see how to work out the details.

Base case is obvious, as said.

Successor case:
Suppose $V_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal{P}(V_\beta)$ for fixed successor $\alpha$. Then $V_{\alpha+1}= \mathcal{P}(\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal{P}(V_\beta))$. I WTS $V_{\alpha+1} =\bigcup_{\beta < {\alpha+1}} \mathcal{P}(V_\beta)$.

Limit case: Suppose $V_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal{P}(V_\beta)$ for all $\alpha < \lambda$. Then I WTS $V_\lambda = \bigcup_{\beta < \lambda} \mathcal{P}(V_\beta)$.

Comment: Have you seen transfinite induction before?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes, I just learned it.

Comment: Why would you call this Zermelo hierarchy?

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's what my books calls it. It's used as a synonym for Cumulative Hierarchy.

Comment: Realy??? What book is that?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Devlin's The Joy of Sets

Comment: Well, that's a first. I know that Zermelo was the one coming up with this. But nevertheless, the hierarchy is usually named after von Neumann.

Comment: @CuriousKid7 Well, can you use transfinite induction to prove this? The base case is easy - both definitions give $V_0=\emptyset$. So can you do the limit step? How about the successor step? (Note that transfinite induction doesn't have to break into three pieces, there's a one-step version, but in my experience it's easier in the beginning to do it this way.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I edited my question to reflect using induction. But I can't really figure out how to complete the steps.

Comment: Maybe first try to show that the $V_\alpha$'s are transitive (in both definitions), and that $\beta <\alpha \implies V_\beta \subset V_\alpha$ (noting that "$x$ is transitive" is equivalent to "$x\subset P(x)$").

Comment: @Max Ok I proved that they are transitive, and your strategy seems promising, but I'm still not managing to work it out. Could you maybe explain a bit more?

Comment: Well if $\alpha = \delta +1$, there is a largest $\beta <\alpha$, namely $\delta$. So all the $V_\beta$, $\beta <\alpha$, are subsets of $V_\delta$, and so $\displaystyle\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha} P(V_\beta) \subset P(V_\delta)$. The converse inclusion shoyldn't be a problem. Can you see how this changes in the limit case ?