# For $\alpha$ a limit ordinal, show $V_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}P(V_{\beta})$

Tags: set-theory

For $\alpha$ a limit ordinal, I would like to show

> > $V_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}P(V_{\beta})$

where the $V$'s are members of the cumulative hierarchy and $P$ is the power set.

(This is a continuation of [Showing equivalence of definitions for Zermelo Hierarchy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2228629/showing-equivalence-of-definitions-for-zermelo-hierarchy), where Max ostensibly provided a solution in for a successor ordinal)

In the cumulative hierarchy, for a limit ordinal $\alpha$, $V_{\alpha}:=\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}V_{\beta}$, so I would like to show

> > $\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}V_{\beta}=\bigcup_{\beta\lt\alpha}P(V_{\beta})$

Can I say that for any $\beta\lt\alpha$, there is a $\beta$' with $\beta\lt\beta'\lt\alpha$ such that $V_{\beta'}=P(V_{\beta})$.

And conversely, for any such $\beta'$, there is a $\beta$ again with  $V_{\beta'}=P(V_{\beta})$, establishing inclusion in both dorections?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the following $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal (and $\alpha > 0$):

Your approach *almost* works. First of all, for all $\beta < \alpha$
$$
V_{\beta+1} = \mathcal P (V_\beta),
$$
so that $$\{ \mathcal P(V_\beta) \mid \beta < \alpha\} \subseteq \{ V_{\beta} \mid \beta < \alpha\} $$

The inverse inclusion does not hold, since for limit ordinals $\beta < \alpha$ (including $\beta = 0$) there is **no** $\gamma$ such that $V_{\beta} = \mathcal P(V_{\gamma})$.

But if $\beta < \alpha$ is a limit ordinal, then $V_{\beta} = \bigcup_{\gamma < \beta} V_{\gamma}$ which inductively yields that for all $x \in V_{\beta}$ there is some $\gamma < \beta$ such that $x \in V_{\gamma+1} = \mathcal P(V_{\gamma})$, so that
$$
\bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} V_\beta = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} \mathcal P(V_{\beta})
$$ 
after all.

Comment: Thanks, Stefan. Do you have to modify anything if you are dealing with, for example, $\omega+n$ where $n$ is a natural number. I.e., a limit ordinal plus a successor ordinal. With regards,

Comment: For successor ordinals, the formula becomes rather useless: $V_{\lambda + n} = \mathcal P^n (V_{\lambda}) = \bigcup_{\alpha \le \lambda + n} V_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\alpha < \lambda + n} P(V_{\alpha})$.

Comment: I'm reviewing, so maybe you would not mind a follow-up. In the first part, is $\alpha$ a limit ordinal? If not, how is it that the LHS which would equal $\{V_{\beta+1}\}$ be contained in $\{V_{\beta}\}$. I.e., would there not be a $\beta+1=\alpha$? Whereas if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal then you could always still have $\beta+1\lt\alpha$. But then, if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, what happens to $\alpha$ in the second part where I presume you are indicating $\beta$ is a limit ordinal? I hope I expressed this clearly and sorry for the imposition. Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew I'm afraid I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, just to simplify: In the first part, is $\alpha$ a limit ordinal? If not, then $\beta+1$ could equal $\alpha$ in which case, would the containment $\{P(V_{\beta}\}\subseteq \{V_{\beta}\}$ still hold? And if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal in the first part, what is it in the second part to make both parts consistent? If this still isn't clear, then please disregard it. Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew I corrected the typo. But what do you mean by "to make both parts consistent"?

Comment: Thanks. That clarifies things. What I meant by consistent was it seemed that $\alpha$ had to have been a limit ordinal in the first part, but not in the second.

Comment: @Andrew Taken a second look on my post: It wasn't a mistake. $\alpha$ is assumed to be a limit ordinal through the entire answer (as it is in your question). I'll revert the previous change at it now is misleading with regard to the rest of my answer.

Comment: I see. At the very beginning, I was confused that $\beta$ is a limit ordinal less than $\alpha$ which is also a limit ordinal. (Have to go out for a while, so thanks)

Comment: Hi Stefan - I saw you are getting your PhD with Ralf Schindler - very impressive. I took a brief look at his "Set Theory" book. Looks pretty difficult, so may be overly ambitious on my part to try and study it. Where do you think it fits in the upper level canon: Jech, Kunen, Kanamori? Is it intended perhaps to be an alternative to Kunen? Thanks and best regards,

Comment: @Andrew Ralf's book *can* be read with little background in set theory (like Kunen's Set Theory) but it's fast paced and therefore I wouldn't necessarily recommend it as a first textbook in advanced set theory. Instead, I think it's best to pick up after having read Kunen or Jech (Kunen is easier to read than Jech) since it offers advanced concepts (and often rather different proofs) that you won't find in either of those. Also: It contains some really tough exercises. Don't be discouraged if you don't solve all of them.

Comment: @Andrew What I didn't make entirely clear in my previous comment: Maybe it's just perception on my part but Ralf seems to have a pretty unique style. There are certain techniques spread widely throughout his entire book that you will not find in Kunen's or Jech's approaches (the converse is true as well, of course). These 'twists', while non-intuitive and hard to grasp at first, have proved incredibly useful to me over the years. (I often jokingly refer to it as 'black magic' -- you'll understand when you see it.)

Comment: Thanks again. I was hoping for an alternative to Kunen. (Jech is OK but what I would call skeletal - no meat on the bones.) One objection I have with Kunen is that it's like a scavenger hunt - he sends you all over the place, even to his other book "Foundations." So there is a lack of continuity. I guess when you cross the great divide into the level of grad texts, you have to be ready to be knocked around a bit.

Comment: @Andrew Are we talking about Kunen's Set Theory (the 2003? edition)? I can't remember it sending me to other textbooks. It may have done that but if so I didn't feel the need to actually follow up on this reference.

Comment: It's 2011 - a retread of his book from a few decades earlier.

Answer (score 2):

The main idea for the reverse inclusion, I think, is that $V_\beta \subset P(V_\beta)$ because $V_\beta$ is transitive.

For the first inclusion, what you said was enough, also perhaps you should say more clearly that (with your notations) $\beta' = \beta +1 $, so that $\beta < \alpha \implies \beta' < \alpha$ (as $\alpha$ is limit)

Answer (score 1):

$b<a\implies b+1<a\implies P(V_b)=V_{b+1}\subset \cup_{c<a}V_c=V_a.$

So $\cup_{b<a}V_{b+1}\subset V_a.$

By transfinite induction every $V_b$ is a transitive set. If $x$ is transitive then $x\subset P(x).$ So $V_b\subset V_{b+1}.$ So $$V_a=\cup_{b<a}V_b\subset\cup_{b<a}V_{b+1}\subset V_a.$$

More generally if $S\subset a=\cup a$ then $\cup S=a\iff \cup_{b\in S}V_b=V_a.$