# Regarding the Continuum Hypothesis and the Constructible Hierarchy

Tags: set-theory

This is from Devlin's "Joy of Sets:

$\mathcal{P}(\omega)\subseteq L_{\omega_1}$. Since $|L_{\omega_1}|=\aleph_1$, this implies that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$.

I can see that the cardinality of $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$ and that $|L_{\omega_1}|=\aleph_1$.

My question is, based on the stated subset relation, how do you know they are equal, i.e., $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$?

**EDIT** As pointed out by Prof. Caicedo, this is in the context of the assumption that $V=L$.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean equal ? One is a proper subset of the other.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Yes, that is my question: How does the author claim they are equal. (In fact, he says "implies at once").

Comment: You should probably review the section on cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: That $\mathcal P (\omega)\subset L_{\omega_1} $ is horribly false unless you assume something like $V=L$, which you should then mention explicitly.

Comment: I would be interested in how Devlin presents $V=L\implies P(\omega)\subset L_{\omega_1}$. The presentation  in Kunen's "Set Theory : An Introduction To Independence Proofs" is clear, but I would not call it obvious.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Very briefly, he says constructible set theory is an extension of ZF, obtained be adjoining the Axiom of Constructibility...the Axiom of Constructibility may be abbreviated as $V=L$.

Comment: I'm familiar with this topic.  To establish that $V=L\implies P(\omega)\subset L_{\omega_1}$  Kunen uses "Lowenheim-Skolem" & a significant preliminary theorem about $L,$ & the Mostowski  Collapse, & some Model Theory.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Maybe I could ask you an off-topic question (I asked and then hesitated a bit earlier today). I'm a self-studier, no math background, 73 and retired. I have made several well-intentioned attempts at Kunen, but find it impenetrable. I'm sure it's largely me, but I would appreciate your opinion. Also if you have any favorite alternatives. Thanks. With regards,

Comment: Kunen' s stye is "compact".  I recall an introductory text  by Suppes.  And a collection (various authors) "Lectures In Set Theory", edited by Morley that has a nice development of Godel's $L$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thanks

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Dear Daniel - In reviewing the answers to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2575838/for-alpha-a-limit-ordinal-show-v-alpha-bigcup-beta-lt-alphapv-bet, in retrospect, I find your answer to be the one I should have accepted. Although I have just learned that I can actually unaccept an answer, I hope you understand that I am reluctant to do so for non-math related reasons. Yet I did want to let you know. So thanks very much. With regards,

Comment: I dk whether you can accept more than one answer. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Only one to a customer; however, I found some other very nice answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully it is clear that the combination of $P(\omega)\subseteq L_{\omega_1}$ and $|L_{\omega_1}|=\aleph_1$ imply that $2^{\aleph_0} \le \aleph_1$.

We also know that $2^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_0$ -- that is Cantor's theorem.

So $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a $\kappa$ with the property $\aleph_0 < \kappa \le \aleph_1$.

Now, since $\aleph_1$ is, *by definition*, the smallest cardinality that is larger than $\aleph_0$, the *only possible* $\kappa$ with this property is $\aleph_1$ itself.